# Does .Net Core support User Secrets per environment?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

Let's say I have connection string for Development environment specified in `appsettings.Development.json` and connection string for the Staging environment specified in `appsettings.Staging.json`

All I need to do to switch between Development and Staging is to navigate to Visual Studio Debug tab in project properties and change the value for `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable.

Now, of course I don't want to have connection string in `appsettings.*.json` for security reasons. So I move it to User Secrets.

Problem is - it seems there is just one `secrets.json` file that is used by all the environments. There are no `secrets.Development.json` or `secrets.Staging.json`. This means after I switch from Development to Staging environment via Visual Studio Debug tab I then also need to change connection strings manually in `secrets.json` which kind of defeats the purpose of having built-in support for the environments.

Is this correct that User Secrets are not supported on per-environment basis? If so - is there another approach that would avoid having to modify Secret connection string manually when switching environments?

Comment: No familiar with the API, but could you use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationextensions.addusersecrets?view=dotnet-plat-ext-1.1#Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_ConfigurationExtensions_AddUserSecrets_Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_IConfigurationBuilder_System_String_ ?

Comment: You can use separate `secrets` files for Debug, Release etc

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos what's the trick to specify different secrets per configuration? The `--configuration` (`-c`) parameter doesn't seem to do anything for `dotnet user-secrets` commands. I've tried with `dotnet --version` 5.0.403.

Comment: @BryanKnox I added that to the question

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you check the tool's parameters with `dotnet user-secrets --help` you'll see you can specify different secrets per configuration (Debug, Release, any other you want) but not per environment. Which is *not* a bad decision if you think about it.

The `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable is meant to tell your application whether the *current machine or container* is a Development, Production or other environment, so it can pick the appropriate settings file. This environment variable isn't expected to change from one application execution to the next. Even when using containers, the environment variables are passed from the host to the container and aren't expected to change during the container's lifetime.

The `secrets` files are supposed to be per machine, for development purposes, so there's no need to keep separate files per environment. It makes much more sense to use separate files for configuration, allowing developers to simply change from Dev to Release or Testing or any other custom configuration they may have.

**Specifying secrets per configuration**

The `dotnet user-secrets` tool works by reading the `UserSecretsId` value from the project file and storing the secrets in a JSON file with the same name, eg `c952ecfc-344e-43e1-bb67-1ac05973d6c6.json`. It's possible to store a `UserSecretsId` for each configuration.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <UserSecretsId>c952ecfc-344e-43e1-bb67-1ac05973d6c6</UserSecretsId>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <UserSecretsId>7D104000-2230-4EDE-8AE6-63BDDA0BD0C5</UserSecretsId>
</PropertyGroup>
```

When the `-c` parameter is used to specify a configuration, the `user-secrets` tool will read the `UserSecretsId` value from the corresponding section and use it to store or read secrets.

The `dotnet user-secrets init` command *doesn't* recognize the `-c` parameter, so the `csproj` file needs to be modified directly.

Once that's done, one can set and read secrets by specifying the configuration, eg :

```
❯ dotnet user-secrets set -c Debug Key1 Value1
Successfully saved Key1 = Value1 to the secret store.

❯ dotnet user-secrets set -c Release Key1 Value2
Successfully saved Key1 = Value2 to the secret store.

❯ dotnet user-secrets list -c Debug
Key1 = Value1

❯ dotnet user-secrets list -c Release
Key1 = Value2
```

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos! Adding the info and examples for the `<PropertyGroup>` elements with the `Condition` attributes in the project file really helps.

Answer (score 14):

I also needed this and I think I've come up with an elegant solution.

`secrets.json` file is shared among all environments you are using, what you can do is add the `environment` parent to each node in the file and then do the little trick (last 2 code fragments).

Suppose you have a configuration, e.g. in `appsettings.json` or `appsettings.{environment}.json`:

```json
{
  "Key1": "value1",
  "Secret1": "<set yourself>"
}
```

and then you have the secret part in `secrets.json`:

```json
{
  "Secret1": "my secret value"
}
```

you can get and bind the whole section easily:

```cs
IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json")
    .AddUserSecrets<Program>()
    .Build();
var myConfiguration = configuration.Get<MyConfiguration>();
```

Now comes the problem, I want to have multiple environments in the `secrets.json`. I personally used to have secrets for all environments I needed and just comment/uncomment what I wanted, however, it's manual work. So I will prefix them with `environment` name instead.

```json
{
  "Development:Secret1": "my secret development value",
  "Staging:Secret1": "my secret staging value"
}
```

You have to load the environment-specific configuration(s) from the `IConfiguration` instance and override the existing `myConfiguration` values using:

```cs
configuration.GetSection(environment).Bind(myConfiguration);
\\ or
configurationRoot.Bind(environment, configuration);
```

And that's it.

If you run it using `environment="Development"`, you will have `"my secret development value"` loaded. If you run it using `environment="Staging"`, you will have `"my secret staging value"` loaded.

#### Additional details

The double dot character (`:`) acts as a new section, so if you write

```json
{
  "Development:Secret1": "my secret development value",
  "Staging:Secret1": "my secret staging value"
}
```

it's the same as

```json
{
  "Development":
  {
    "Secret1": "my secret development value"
  },
  "Staging":
  {
    "Secret1": "my secret staging value"
  }
}
```

the trick is about loading just the environment-specific part and binding it to the `myConfiguration` instance.

I must mention that no matter what environment you are using, all the secrets are actually loaded in the memory.

Comment: Excellent solution! Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use a different secrets file for a different environment. Secrets are located in `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\UserSecrets`

You can create a new folder `MyProject-MyCustomEnvironment` inside the UserSecrets folder, and put in there the desired secrets.json for the new environment. The secrets file must be named exactly `secrets.json`. `MyProject-MyCustomEnvironment` will be the secrets id.

Then, in Program.cs, we just need to pass a different secrets id depending on the environment:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
            
if (builder.Environment.IsEnvironment("MyCustomEnvironment"))
{
    builder.Configuration.AddUserSecrets("MyProject-MyCustomEnvironment");
}
```

When the environment is Development, the standard secrets file is added by default. Its folder name matches the secrets id defined in `UserSecretsId` element of the project csproj file.

Answer (score 0):

The Secret Manager (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-3.1) is designed strictly for development, not any other stage (environment), since it is inherently insecure (local dev secrets are not encrypted). See the warning on the page linked.  So there is no need to have per environment secrets storage vis-a-vis that tool.  For other environments (staging, prod, etc), Microsoft would likely steer you toward their secure secrets storage service -- Key Vault.  You can use the Secret Manager for dev secrets and then store the other environments in Key Vault.  I have done this in many Asp.Net Core apps and it works well.  For Key Vault info, see this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: That's not what the OP asked. The question is if it's possible to pick different "secrets" files on the dev machine simply by changing the environment variable.

Comment: In rereading it, perhaps I did misunderstand.  If OP has these multiple environments all on the same machine and wants to use the development Secrets Manager for all of them, then perhaps my answer is not relevant (although you can use Key Vault locally if you want).

Comment: @BryanLewis yes, you misunderstood me. I am aware of Key Vault. I also used Windows Credential Manager for the same purpose.

Comment: Up voted because this is an important point. The user secrets.json file is only merged with appsettings.json  when IsDevelopment = true.  So you can flip between appsettings in the IDE by setting the environment, but secrets is fixed to development only.

Comment: You forgot about regions. We can have it multiple and separate secret per region still in dev environment.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "out of the box" way to use different secrets per environment. However you can use the [options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0#bind-hierarchical-configuration) to **bind your configs** depending on environment:

Create a secrets.json with your environments at the top level:

```
{
  "Local": {
    "Secret1": "local secret",
    "ConnectionStrings": {
      "DB": "LocalDBConnectionstring"
    }
  },

  "Development": {
    "Secret1": "dev secret",
    "ConnectionStrings": {
      "DB": "DevDBConnectionstring"
    }
  }
}
```

Create classes to map your secret configurations:

```
public class SecretConfigurationEnvironment
{
    public string secret1 { get; set; }
    public ConnectionStringsConfig ConnectionStrings { get; set; }
}

public class ConnectionStringsConfig
{
    public string DB { get; set; }
}
```

Map the secrets to your classes in your program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.Configure<SecretConfigurationEnvironment>(
    builder.Configuration.GetSection(builder.Environment.EnvironmentName));
```

Use your configs with dependencyInjection whereever you need them:

```
public class MyClass {
   private readonly IOptions<SecretConfigurationEnvironment> _secretConfig;

   public MyClass(IOptions<SecretConfigurationEnvironment> secretConfig) {
      _secretConfig = secretConfig
   }

   public void MyMethod() {
      var envDBConnectionString = _secretConfig.value.Connectionstrings.DB
   }
}
```

Now your configs will change depending on your environment and you can still use all your configs stored in the appsettings.environment.json files (also with options if you like)

That being said, here is the usual disclaimer: Don't use secrets.json for staging or production secrets.

The code i provided is for .net 6, wep-api. Older versions or different project-types are very similar though and can be found at the microsoft documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers deal with *"secrets per environment"*. I'm going to focus specifically on *"secret connection string per environment"*, because that's the use case in your question.

There are many ways to do this, but I think below is the simplest.

I assume your secrets file is at the standard location: `~/.microsoft/usersecrets/SECRET_ID/secrets.json` (linux/macos) or `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\UserSecrets\SECRET_ID\secrets.json` (windows).

A `secrets.json` typically has this:

```json
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "MyContext": "Host=...;Port=...;Database=...;Username=...;Password=...;",
}
```

And it's typically read during startup like this:

```cs
builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyContext");
```

The simplest solution is to change that to:

```json
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "Development": "Host=...;Port=...;Database=...;Username=...;Password=...;",
  "Staging":     "Host=...;Port=...;Database=...;Username=...;Password=...;",
  "Production":  "Host=...;Port=...;Database=...;Username=...;Password=...;",
}
```

And

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var environmentName = builder.Environment.EnvironmentName;
// ...
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString(environmentName);
```

Now the correct connection string will be read for each environment.