# Does .Net Core can change User Secret based on Environment in launch settings?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1, user-secret

On my dev machine I store `connection strings` in all of my `Appsettings{environment}.json` files.
When I have some kind of problem in `Production` environment I change the `launch.settings` file to `Production` and then I can debug the solution using `Production` database.

I would like to move some credentials keys from my `Appsettings` files and store them in `UserSecret` on my dev machine.

From my understanding the `UserSecret` doesn't support `UserSecret{environment}.json` like `appsettings` does.
  [Does .Net Core support User Secrets per environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60437357/does-net-core-support-user-secrets-per-environment)

So how can I use `UserSecret` on my local machine but yet keep the ability to change the connection string when environment changes in `LaunchSettings`?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the User Secrets are **only for development** and not intended for production. Production secrets shouldn't be used for development or test. Secrets shouldn't be deployed with the app.

You could could try to use multiple connection strings, like: `ConnectionStrings:productionDB` and `ConnectionStrings:developmentDB`.

Besides, production secrets should be accessed through a controlled means like **environment variables** or **Azure Key Vault**. You can store and protect Azure test and production secrets with the [Azure Key Vault configuration provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

More detail information, you could refer the following articles:

[Safe storage of app secrets in development in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=windows)

[Use multiple environments in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

[Storing production secrets in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40131672/storing-production-secrets-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: `ConnectionStrings:productionDB` this approach is not supported using user secret, this was referred to appsettings which I think I will go with that direction.